# What does a hashtag # mean after a git branch

Tags: git, branch

When I created a repo there was a # after the master
branch `(master #)`
then creating a branch,  it also had the # `(branch #)`
It disappeared after adding and committing. 
However, now there is not a master branch in the repo, just a created branch, where did it go? does the initial # have anything to do with it?

I can not find a reference to the meaning of # in the docs.

Comment: It does not mean anything in Git as it is not a Git feature. This must be something your environment is doing for you. You will have to find out what your environment means by that.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your terminal, or a screen capture ?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about something in your shell prompt maybe? You need to be more specific about what `(master #)` is and where it shows up. And if it's your shell, you need to explain what shell environment you are using.

Comment: I'll look around in my shell for what it means and I'll also try to post an image.  I'm using the terminal in RubyMine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same git prompt settings adapted from udacity git course. The hash sign indicates the current checked out branch has no commits yet.

ref:
https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud775